# Ruby On Rails scaffold need to include foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm learning the basics of ruby on rails and I want to make some simple queries but I have a doubt:

I will have these models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  has_many :orders
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, counter_cache: true
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

Now, I will use scaffold to generate all the things, and I want to know if I have to directly put the foreign keys in the scaffols, like:

**rails generate scaffold Adress street:string number:integer client_id:integer**

Or when I make those associations and then migrate my db they will be implicit?

I don't know if I explain myself in the best way.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, first you should generate parent model scaffold after that you can generate child scaffold and point out foreign like the above

Comment: rails g scaffold client client_name:string

rails g scaffold address client_id:integer address1:string

like this

Comment: So, If I generate:

**Adress street:string number:integer**

It will never be associated to any client, even if then I wrote :

 **belongs_to :client** in Client's Model

Correct?

Comment: Yep exactly rather you need to add client:referrence to the above command.

Comment: See the below answer it will helpful

Comment: Foreign keys are always stored on the model calling `belongs_to`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yep, there is no reference. You need to either pass the `client_id` or a reference to Client model, e.g:

```
rails generate scaffold Address street:string number:integer client_id:integer:index
```

or

```
rails generate scaffold Address street:string number:integer client:references
```

Answer (score 1):

Either, in **rails 4** you can use belongs_to this way:

Assume that you have a user model in your application

```
rails g scaffold comment belongs_to:user text:string
```

it generates that class in your migrate folder:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :text
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

you should execute `rake db:migrate` then, this command create  *user_id* properties as a index column in your database table.